# How to divide a list of numbers in a sine function to plot it using matplotlib in python?

Tags: python

```
i = range(0,40,1)
y = 0.1 * cos((i)/20 * pi)
```

The error I get is this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'`
```

I am not sure how to remove that error. I type-casted i to int, but its a list, thus can't be type-casted. I am following this example. http://msenux.redwoods.edu/math/python/simple.php

Comment: good about the typo, but have a look at my answer about `import`ing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using pylab's `arange`, not simple python `range`. And this is the problem when `importing *`: you don't know which method comes from where. Import just pylab and reference to all its methods/constants with `pylab.`. You will really love this way of programming when you've got several imports.

```
import pylab
i = pylab.arange(0, 40, 1) # or pylab.arange(40) will suffice
y = 0.1 * pylab.cos(i / 20. * pylab.pi)
```

will work.

Comment: Also you'll want to divide by `20.0` (a float), or `from __future__ import division`, or use Python 3. Otherwise, with int division, `i/20` will just be zeroes and ones.

Comment: Why exactly would it be zeroes and ones? Can any elucidate a bit more!

Comment: with `i/20` and Python 2.x you have an integer division, i.e. `5/20 = 0`, `21/20 = 1`

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to use i % 20 ?

Comment: @Hiccup: `%` does [something completely different](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex). I think you do want division.

Answer (score 2):

You should perhaps loop over `i` to get the individual values: `range` returns a list.

```
>>> for i in range(0, 40):
...     print cos((i)/20.0 * pi)
```

Or to get the values:

```
y = [cos((i)/20.0 * pi) for i in range(0, 40)]
```